# Access SQL Query Results in Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

How can I access 2nd value returned from SQL Query?  Obviously, I assign the 1st value returned to my drop down list, but how can I later in my runaquery method get the employeeid value?  The below is what I would like to do, but unsure of how to get that value other than a 2nd call to sql server and run the query again...

```
private void populate DropDownMainScreen()
{
  this.ddlemployee.DataSource = DoThis();
  this.ddlemployee.DataTextField = "employeename";
  this.ddlemployee.DataValueField = "employeename";
  this.ddlemployee.DataBind();
}

private void DoThis()
{
  SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  SqlQueryBuilder.Append = "Select employeeID, employeename from personell";
  //Actually run the query here
}
private void runaquery()
{
  string employeename = this.ddlemployee.SelectedItem.Value;
  int campaignID = ;
  Showmetheresults(RunSQLQuery, employeename, employeeID)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
private void populate DropDownMainScreen()
{
  this.ddlemployee.DataSource = DoThis();
  this.ddlemployee.DataTextField = "employeename";
  this.ddlemployee.DataValueField = "employeeID";
  this.ddlemployee.DataBind();
}

private void DoThis()
{
  SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  SqlQueryBuilder.Append = "Select employeeID, employeename from personell";
  //Actually run the query here
}
private void runaquery()
{
  string employeename = this.ddlemployee.SelectedItem.DataTextField;
  string employeID = this.ddlemployee.SelectedItem.Value;
  int campaignID = ;
  Showmetheresults(RunSQLQuery, employeename, employeeID)
}
```